# Clearing all Text Boxes within a Table within a Panel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I have 16 text-boxes within a panel. I am trying to create a button that will clear all text out of each box. Currently I'm using the `txtbox.text = ""` option, but there has got to be a better way to do it.

I have tried using `panel.controls.clear()` but that doesn't seem to work either.

```xml
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAddNewPeopleRecord" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:Label ID="lblAddNewPeopleRecord" runat="server" Visible="true">Add To People Table</asp:Label>
    <asp:Table runat="server" class="tblAddNewRecord">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">ID</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeoplePersonID"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">First Name</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleFirstName"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Middle Initial</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleMiddleInitial"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Last Name</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleLastName"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Street 1</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleStreet1"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Street 2</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleStreet2"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">City</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleCity"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">State</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleState"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Zip Code</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleZipCode"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Country</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleCountry"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Phone 1</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeoplePhone1"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Phone 2</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeoplePhone2"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Fax</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleFax"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Cell Phone</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleCellPhone"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Email</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleEmail"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="tblCell">
                <asp:Label class="tblCellLabel" runat="server">Notes</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox class="tblCellTextbox" runat="server" ID="txtbxPeopleNotes"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>

    <asp:Button runat="server" class="btnResetRecord" ID="btnAddNewPeopleResetRecords" Text="Reset Fields" OnClick="btnAddNewPeopleResetRecords_Click" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" class="btnAddNewRecord" ID="btnAddNewRecordToPeople" Text="Add Record To People Table" OnClick="btnAddNewRecordToPeople_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I'm using the code below. When I click the button, the page does nothing.

```
protected void btnAddNewPeopleResetRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resetAllTextBoxes(pnlAddNewPeopleRecord);
}

private void resetAllTextBoxes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel pnlAddNewPeopleRecord)
{
    foreach(System.Web.UI.Control c in pnlAddNewPeopleRecord.Controls)
    {
        if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)
        {
            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)c).Text = ""; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this WebForms?  I'm not very familiar with webforms but my first suggestion would be to just utilize javascript (particularly jQuery) to clear the values, and that can be done entirely client side.  If that isn't an option, you may need to look into Ajax with WebForms to allow the button to call to the server without a full postback - that's the basic idea in MVC, I'm not sure how well that applies to WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this server-side then you solution is the best way. It could be neatened up if linq is available to you.

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

private void resetAllTextBoxes(Panel pnlAddNewPeopleRecord)
{
    foreach(var control in pnlAddNewPeopleRecord.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        control.Text = string.Empty; 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this client-side if you don't need to post-back to the server. Using jquery for ease.

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Textboxes" onclick="ClearTextboxes();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClearTextboxes()
    {
        $(".tblCellTextbox").val("");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When I add the Javascript, the fields do not clear out. I also tried the first suggestion, but that didn't work either